# Commutativity of a $G \neq \bigcup_{H\leq G\\H\neq G} H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm supposed to prove that every group $G$ with $$G \neq \bigcup_{H\leq G\\H\neq G} H$$ is commutative. How could one go on about that?

Answer (score 4):

For any $g\in G$, $\langle g\rangle$ is always a subgroup of $G$ and is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $g$. If $G$ satisfies your condition, then there exists $g\in G$ such that the only subgroup of $G$ that contains $g$ is $G$ itself.  In this case $G = \langle g\rangle$. Therefore, $G$ is even cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If $G$ *is not cyclic* then for any $g\in G$, $H_g:=\{g^k,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.